# What sort of thing would first years be taught in DADA?

Tags: harry-potter, defence-against-the-dark-arts

I am writing a Harry Potter fanfic but I can't figure out what my character should learn in her first Defence Against the Dark Arts lesson.

Could you help?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction and Fantasy! This seems like quite a simple question that might be found by some quick internet searching; how much did you look into this before posting?

Answer (score 5):

From Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone there's no specific mention of what a student learns in their very first lesson. This is what's said about it;

> The class everyone had really been looking forward to was Defence
> Against the Dark Arts, but Quirrell’s lessons turned out to be a bit
> of a joke. His classroom smelled strongly of garlic, which everyone
> said was to ward off a vampire he’d met in Romania and was afraid
> would be coming back to get him one of these days. His turban, he told
> them, had been given to him by an African prince as a thank-you for
> getting rid of a troublesome zombie, but they weren’t sure they
> believed this story.
>
> For one thing, when Seamus Finnigan asked eagerly to hear how Quirrell had fought off the zombie, Quirrell went pink and
> started talking about the weather; for another, they had noticed that
> a funny smell hung around the turban, and the Weasley twins insisted
> that it was stuffed full of garlic as well, so that Quirrell was
> protected wherever he went.
>
> Harry was very relieved to find out that
> he wasn’t miles behind everyone else. Lots of people had come from
> Muggle families and, like him, hadn’t had any idea that they were
> witches and wizards. There was so much to learn that even people like
> Ron didn’t have much of a head start.

There is also mention of

> Different ways of treating werewolf bites

later in the book. And that's all there is.

Comment: I like this answer -- I was going to leave an answer stating I thought that Year one was the one year where JKR did not specify any DADA coursework. DVK's answer from the Wiki is pretty extensive, but I would want to know *exactly* where each item is cited in canon. :)

Comment: Only the werewolf bites are mentioned in canon. The rest come from supplemental books and the pottermore website

Answer (score 0):

[Harry Potter Wikia](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Defence_Against_the_Dark_Arts) has you covered (and is a good source for lists like this):

- Curse of the Bogies (mentioned)
- Knockback Jinx
- Verdimillious
- Wand-Lighting Charm: Lumos
- Curing werewolf bites
- Gnomes
- Doxies
- Snails

In addition, their textbook (["The Dark Forces: A Guide to Self-Protection"](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/The_Dark_Forces%3a_A_Guide_to_Self-Protection)) contained additional material since it was also used for 4th year. As listed on Pottermore:

- Curse of the Bogies
- Knockback Jinx
- Wand-Lighting Charm
- Werewolf Bites

and

- Green Sparks
- Hags
- Red Caps
- Red Sparks
- Smokescreen Spell
- Vampires
- Wand-Extinguishing Charm
- Zombies